# EF Core 5 lambda expression for removign more than 10 records based on where condition

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

This is my SQl query:

```
; WITH cte(rownum) AS
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Col2 DESC) --date c
    FROM
        [table]
    WHERE
        [Col1] = @col   //filter 
)
DELETE FROM cte 
WHERE rownum > 10
```

Please let me know how to convert this SQL to an EF Core lambda expression
Thanks
EDIT: i know remove Range ,,but how to row number function to in lambda?

EDIT:

```
await _unitOfWork.tables.DeleteAsync(  ?);
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a description of what you are trying to do with that query.

Comment: @Progman i have to remove old records in the table ,,when 11th record inserted i have to remove 1st record based on date i.e col2

Comment: use skip? eg. await _unitOfWork.tables.Remove(await _unitOfWork.tables.Skip(10))?

Comment: thanks but i have filter condition  [Col1] = @col  and ORDER BY Col2 DESC

Comment: And? _unitOfWork.tables.Where(condition).OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).Skip(10) ?

Comment: Thanks @RandRandom for your anser..i will check

Comment: You cannot execute analogue of your SQL via EF and LINQ. Only via third party extensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I mock as below. Use `RemoveRange`, `OrderByDescending` and `Skip`. Hope this would help:

```
using (var db = new MyDbContext())
{
  db.Persons.Add(new Person(){id=1,name="Danny",age=20});
  db.Persons.Add(new Person(){id=2,name="Archer",age=55});
  db.Persons.Add(new Person(){id=3,name="John",age=18});
  db.Persons.Add(new Person(){id=4,name="Cena",age=13});
  db.Persons.Add(new Person(){id=5,name="T-Rax",age=4});

  db.SaveChanges();
  Console.WriteLine("Before removing ....");
  foreach( var p in db.Persons)
  {
    Console.WriteLine($"Name :{p.name} , Age : {p.age}");
  }
  Console.WriteLine("\n");

  db.Persons.RemoveRange(db.Persons.Where(i => i.age<50).OrderByDescending(i => i.age).Skip(2).ToList());
  db.SaveChanges();

  Console.WriteLine("After removing ....");
  foreach( var p in db.Persons)
  {
    Console.WriteLine($"Name :{p.name} , Age : {p.age}");
  }
}
Console.Read();
```

Comment: as per suggestion  @Rand Random my code works..any way i wil accept ur ansewr

Answer (score 1):

In EF ALL data modifications should go through ChangeTracker. And you cannot execute such query via LINQ, which is preliminary QUERY language extension not DML.

Anyway, leaving here example how to do that EF Core extension [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore) (note, that I'm one of the creators)

```cs
var query = table
    .Where(t => t.Col1 == col1)
    .Select(t => new
    {
        RN = Sql.Ext.RowNumber().Over().OrderByDesc(t.Col2).ToValue()
    })
    .Where(x => x.RN > 10)
    .Delete();
```